# Implicit conversion from IEnumerable<int> to IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, implicit-conversion

I haven't used `dynamic` much in C# so far, so I came across a (small) problem when trying to create a simple `WebGrid`-like component for learning purposes.

The normal `WebGrid` takes as its data source an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, so I emulated that. Then I created a view like the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<int>

@{
  MyWebGrid grid = new MyWebGrid(Model);
}
```

In the MVC project, this leads to a runtime conversion error, so I created a small console application (this doesn't compile of course):

```
class Program
{
  class Foo { public int Id { get; } }

  static void Main()
  {
    CheckConversion(new List<int>().AsEnumerable()); // Error

    CheckConversion(new List<Foo>()); // works

    int x = 5;
    CheckSingleParameterConversion(x); // works
  }

  private static void CheckConversion(IEnumerable<dynamic> source) { }
  private static void CheckSingleParameterConversion(dynamic val) { }
}
```

The error (in short): Cannot convert from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

What is the exact reasoning behind these differing behaviors? I know that `dynamic` is a reference type and could thus understand why there might be some problem with the `IEnumerable<int>` here, but why does it work in the single parameter case then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not in `dynamic` itself, it's all about `variance`.

As said in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters)

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type
>   for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the
>   resulting constructed type.

So `IEnumerable<int>` cannot be casted to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, because `int` is a value type and `dynamic` is just an `object` marked with special attribute.